# Avidemux changes colors in my video?

Tags: colors, video-editing, avidemux

I'm just using avidemux to crop some video that has black borders, but for some reason, the colors change horribly the minute Avidemux gets hold of the footage.

Before:

[image: Raw footage colors]

During:

[image: Colors during]

After:

[image]

The first screenshot is from Windows Media Player playing the raw video, before cropping. (I have cropped the screenshots to the same portion of the screen, or you'd see the massive gulf of black border I'm trying to remove). The second screenshot is from inside Avidemux, and is identical to what I get when Windows Media Player plays the video after I've cropped it in avidemux. No other filters were applied.

EDIT: Since there seems to be some confusion, the third screenshot is from Windows Media Player again, proving that the exported **video file** has this color issue.

What causes this and how can I fix it? I'm fairly new to video editing, so I'm not even sure how to describe the problem other than "it looks wrong". The input video is decoded with lavcodec. Using the 64 bit version of the program does not help.

Comment: What software are you trying to capture? Also, does this effect any other software?

Comment: @K.A I'm trying to edit some AVI files.

Comment: I mean, what are the screenshots you posted of? Is it possible it's just that software?

Comment: @K.A The first screenshot is from Windows Media Player playing the raw video, before cropping. The second screenshot is from inside Avidemux, and is identical to what I get when Windows Media Player plays the video after I've cropped it in avidemux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out:

The video portion of the file was encoded with msvideo1, as deduced with ffprobe. Re-encoding it into mpeg4 with ffmpeg, fixes the problem. I guess avidemux can't read msvideo correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is to do with MSvideo 1. A fix is to add a video filter from within AVIdemux (swap UV) this will make the colours back to how they should look. Click preview to see the effect. You won't see the colour fix while editing but you will when you export the final video (don't use copy mode for the video).